# VBA changes number decimal number when inserted into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I made a script in VBA that loads a decimal number into a class module, where the variable is stored as a Single. The script then opens another file and inserts the value. However when inserting it the value is changed to 12 significant decimals- and rounded wrong.

An example is 1274,94 to 1274,93994140625.

When printing the value directly from the class is gives the right number, however printing the cell value also gives the wrong number.

Comment: Explanation to this issue [can be found here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior from float numbers in programming. You can round to the right amount of decimals with

```
Math.round(number, numberDecimals)
```